# Akeneo permission management

Tags: php, permissions, roles, akeneo

I am currently working on the implementation of Akeneo CE to improve product management and I would like to manage permissions so that people are able to act on specific attributes/fields, this will allow to minimize the risks of errors and allow us to have customer input some very specific data.

I have seen this [document](https://help.akeneo.com/v2-users-and-permissions/119-v2-set-rights-on-your-catalog) for v2 that appears to perfectly cover my needs but this functionality seems to have been lost in versions 7.0.26. Is my understanding correct? I have seen that there is a "role" functionality but it appears to be far less granular than what was available in the past.

Is there any solution to have the granularity back?
I am also trying to identify when in the version history that function got lost but change logs are limited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The permissions about fields were never part of Akeneo CE. The permissions are an Enterprise feature for the Enterprise Edition.
They still exists in the latest version of Akeneo EE
https://help.akeneo.com/serenity-permissions/40-serenity-set-rights-on-your-catalog

The Community version only allows you to access to a "high granularity" level (read/edit/write entities).

Comment: Thank you for the reply, as per my question v2 seemed to have that functionality as detailed here https://help.akeneo.com/v2-users-and-permissions/119-v2-set-rights-on-your-catalog . This can be a bit of dealbreaker for Akeneo CE. I will have to search for other PIMs

Comment: @AlessandroBettoni as you can see in the previous page ( https://help.akeneo.com/en_US/v2-themes-for-peter ) even in v2 "Set rights on your catalog" is an EE (enterprise edition) feature.
=> cf the [EE] tag before the name of the feature